# batch to adjust Daylight saving changes run by task scheduler

Tags: batch-file

I need to change time on PCs to adjust Daylight saving changes run by task scheduler so, I made this small batch file what I need is to know if that code is correct because I feel there is something in correct in it specially on the 
Milliseconds part the final result is not normal when I compare it with first line that print time `ECHO Current Time is %TIME%`

**Notes**

1. I can not use `Pwoershell`
2. it should work with `windows 7`, `XP` and `windows server 2003`

thanks in advance for help

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Daylight Saving

SET CurrentHours=%TIME:~0,2%

ECHO.
ECHO Current Time is %TIME%

REM ECHO %TIME:~0,2% REM --- Hours
REM ECHO %TIME:~3,2% REM --- Minutes
REM ECHO %TIME:~6,2% REM --- Seconds
REM ECHO %TIME:~9,3% REM --- Milliseconds


if %CurrentHours% LSS 23 SET /a CurrentHours=%CurrentHours%+1
if %CurrentHours% EQU 23 SET CurrentHours=00

TIME %CurrentHours%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%.%TIME:~9,3%

ECHO.
ECHO Time has been adjusted for Daylight saving changes.Current time now is %TIME%


PAUSE
REM --- EXIT
```

Comment: Doesn't Windows automatically change the time for Daylight Saving?

Comment: sam, please revisit your previously answered questions marking your preferred solutions as accepted. This isn't a salaried service, our motivation to help is boosted by the appreciation we receive from those we helped. The points system from accepted answers goes some way to help in that regard, and helps the site as a whole. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a feature for this: "Disable auto update setting of Windows clock to DST." Then you don't have to get up by 2:00 AM to do it manually. This web page tutorial explains it in some detail.

http://in5stepstutorials.com/windows-7/prevent-automatically-changing-windows-time-to-dst.php